# Mvc RenderAction performance vs RenderPartial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

Hi I was wondering if mvc C#s render action was as efficient as calling the partial in my review directly, and if not, how inefficient it was.

Answer (score 7):

`RenderAction` will certainly be slower than `RenderPartial`. The difference will depend on how much additional work your child action is performing relative to the parent action. For a very simple child action the difference should be pretty small (few % points slower). Without knowing your particular application it's hard to tell. If you are worried about performance you should do some measurements.